# Application functionality changes when run on device

Tags: ios

I've found that my application stops its timer when the device goes to the lock screen on actual device, but it works perfectly on the simulator.

Is that because I haven't released the app, so an actual device won't let me keep working on the lock screen?  Or is it a bug in my code?

I've written an `NSLog()` statement to monitor my application's timer action, it keeps working when the simulator goes to the lock screen,
but on an actual device it stops.

I'm so frustrated because I don't know why there are these differences between the device and the simulator, and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: timers don't work in the background.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045405/timer-when-leaving-app-and-returning-on-ios/27046921#27046921

Comment: but I didn't press home button and leave app to the background, just lock screen while app in foreground.  it still can't keep timer working ? because I saw other clock app's timer still working even when app screen locking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is implement applicationWillEnterForeground and applicationDidEnterBackground to persist the state of your timer, and resume it whenever the app opens again.

You may also want to use [UILocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/) to schedule a notification when your timer finishes.

[Here is another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302846/executing-code-when-the-application-is-in-background-not-working-on-physical-de/31303505#31303505) about using UILocalNotification with timers that you may find useful.